# Finding max in an array using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion

Suppose I have the following declarations:

```
int arr[5] = {1,10,9,28,3};
int low = 0;
int high = 4; 
int largest = findLargest(ar, low, high);
```

I am suppose to write a "findLargest" function using recursion, and this is what I got

```
 int findLargest(int arr[], int low, int high)
 {      
    if (low == high)
        return arr[low];
    return max(arr[low], findLargest(arr, low+1, high));
 }
```

The output was `28`, which was expected. However, I don't really understand how does this recursive function "compare" the values. (By that I mean I don't see any operators such as `>`, `<`. The only operator that I see is `==`). So, how does this recursive function compare the values in the array?

Comment: `std::max` does the comparison.

Comment: Think about what happens when you call this function with an array that has only one element. Simple, right? Then think about what happens when you call it with an array that has two elements. Then three, then four, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The recursion is using the [`std::max`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/max/) function, which uses `operator<`. The maximum of the subarray `[a;b]` is the maximum between `a` and the maximum of the subarray `[a + 1;b]` (Which is `a` if `a = b`).